# Sinhala Language not display in chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-10

I recently upgrade windows 8.1 pro version to windows 10. Then I use Google chrome browser, it doesn't show the Sinhala language. In windows 8.1 it showed though. I search internet I found [article](http://www.aluth.com/2014/10/Chrome-stopped-showing-sinhala-unicode-characters-Fix.html) saying (this article in sinhala language) paste

```
chrome://flags/#disable-direct-write
```

on address bar and Enable **Disable DirectWrite**. I did it though it didn't work. But in my chrome on Ubuntu 14.04 shows sinhala language. (I'm on dual boot). can any one help me please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you Dinith for your answer but I came up with this solution.
Install "iskoola pota" font and it work.

Answer (score 6):

Try this,
Windows search -> search for "optional features"
Click on "add an optional feature" (The settings panel will open)
Click on "add feature" and install both the sinhala supplement fonts
Restart Your PC